# What am I? by SC - #3

Tags: riddle, word

Both of my riddles are answered, so here you go :)

I love to start with every single digit integer ranged from 1-9 but can't start with 9

First version of one of my capabilities has a common number with a popular boeing model

Orion Nebula and I have a common abbreviation

A Mercedes Benz automobile model and what I did, have a common abbreviation

Born in the early 1900s

Hint:

> cst1992's answer for nebula is M78 and Boeing 787. M78 is wrong, but even if it was correct, Boeing doesn't have to be the same number. Every line in the riddle is standalone. But when they are together, they mean something. Start digging from Orion Nebula, it is the starting point of the riddle.

Hint 2 (I thought my question was clear, I am giving an imaginary example solution):

> Orion Nebula is also known as M78, Company X has a TV which is known as M78. Mercedes has a car model named ML60, Company X has a phone named ML60. By first version of capabilities; "X" is a phone company but also produces tv so has different capabilities, and has a phone which is 787 Ghz. Boeing has B787, so answer could be company X for this example. Like I said on comment, your clues are not connected to each other for this question. By collecting them all, you will finalise your answer.

Hint 3:

> I have blue colour

Hint 4 (Orion Nebula's starting point):

> M42 is the first abbreviation of Orion Nebula. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M42

had to give all possible hints because of low interest in the puzzle :)
**with all the given hints, it became relatively easy, so first one to answer every connection will be selected as the correct answer.**

Comment: Every integer except 9... could you be more specific? I mean it's from -infinity to infinity except for 9.

Comment: this is my mistake. single digits ranged from 1 to 9, but not 9. thanks for pointing out

Comment: Any more hints? What I'm not clear is "First version of one of my capabilities..." what do you mean by that? Also what is meant by "A Mercedes Benz automobile model and what I did"? That also doesn't make sense.

Comment: added an example solution for you @cst1992

Comment: well, I've even given the m42 reference. the answer is in there. I guess people are not interested with this kind of puzzle/riddle combo. Will give the answer today if no one is willing to solve

Comment: @SirSC hint #4 says it has blue color means the name has it or object itself is in that color. Again  " A Mercedes Benz automobile model and what I did, " means that something it done or it is like the common abbreviation it has ?

Comment: Common abbr. Production is also known as we did this :) name doesnt contain blue but represented with colors and one of them is blue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am:

> BMW

Orion Nebula and I have a common abbreviation

> With the hint types and information, and the popularity of M42, it is a BMW engine, which is listed in the link given

I love to start with every single digit integer ranged from 1-9 but can't start with 9

> BMW models start with every number except 9. 2 series, 3 series, etc

First version of one of my capabilities has a common number with a popular boeing model

> BMW Dixi is the first car made by BMW, which has a 747cc engine. Reference to Boeing 747

A Mercedes Benz automobile model and what I did, have a common abbreviation

> BMW S55 Engine and Mercedes Benz S55 model

Born in the early 1900s

> BMW was founded in 1916

Answer (score 2):

I have the nebula and Boeing figured out, and they could be

> M78 in the Orion constellation and the 787 Dreamliner

Comment: not M78, but keep digging. you are on correct path :) but even if it was m78, boeing can still be 737. they are different

Comment: you wanna improve your answer with the given hints?

Comment: I did come to a similar partial answer, but it doesn't fit either. Especially the main clue: likes to start with 1-9 but not 9. If I figure that one out, I'll post it in the answer.

Comment: @SirSC I figured out the M42 already, as it's another name for the Orion itself, instead of something just in the neighborhood of it. Blue color is a new hint, so maybe I could use that.